# How to use 'Reattach To Process' in 'Post-build event command line' Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, attach-to-process

How to use 'Reattach To Process'  in 'Post-build event command line'  VS2017?

I'm working on 'visual studio 2017' 'solution',
I want to 'Reattach To Process' immediately after build.

I want to know how to use the command line for 'Reattach To Process'.

Answer (score 0):

> a third option is to attach to the process by running from the Windows
> command line.

Try to use `vsjitdebugger.exe -p <ProcessId>`  .

Document: [Attach to running processes with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022#BKMK_Attach_to_a_process_on_a_remote_computer)

Comment: @CW park Hi, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?